# (UK) LED lights flash once after being switched off

Tags: lighting, led, flashing

I had a nice kitchen light fitting with 5x 20watt halogen bulbs (G4), and the transformer blew. I thought that now would be a great time to upgrade the transformer/fitting to support LED lighting.

I bought 5x LED lights (3watts each), and an LED driver (max 18watt rating, 240v AC to 12v DC) to replace the old transformer within the light fitting. Everything seemed to work fine, the lights switch on perfectly, but the moment I switch off the light, the bulbs switch off, but after 1 second, they flash once, and then switch off. (Not sure how relevant this is, but the switch is a simple on/off switch, rather than a dimmer).

I've tried searching various forums, and I havent been able to find a definitive answer. I did however read something about RC Contact Suppressors or CapLoads being used, but wasn't sure whether this applied to me. I was hoping maybe someone here may be able to shed some light for me.

Does anyone know the reason for this? Should I be worried? Is there any way I can resolve this?

[LED Driver](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/UK-STOCK-LED-Driver-Power-Supply-Transformer-240V-DC-12V/291227665215?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=591082544360&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649)

[LED lights](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B071J2ZRC4/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: Tell us more about the **switch** in question. Were the old ones 12V?  Was there anything else using that circuit?

Comment: no, you should not be worried, you actually have (aside from that quirk) a  nice LED driver with lots of output capacitance, which is a a good thing.